# Vue JS via CDN - why does adding a component replace the entire template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm making a vue js app using the CDN like this:

```
        <div id="bookingApp">
            <select-service />
            <div>
                Hello there
            </div>
        </div>
```

... and in js ...

```
const SelectService = {
    template: '<h1>In Here!!</h1>',
    setup() {

    }
}

const bookingApp = Vue.createApp({
    components: { "select-service": SelectService },
    data() {
        return {
            sid: -1,
            rid: -1
        }
    }
});

bookingApp.mount('#bookingApp');
```

... However, in #bookingApp it only shows "In Here!!" and not "Hello there" below it.

If I remove the  then it shows "Hello there" as expected.

Why is it that I can't have  component and still show the Hello there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use self-closing tags for Vue components in DOM templates as HTML only allows self closing for well known types like `<input>` and `<img>`.

For more details see the documentation:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats